# retreiveing website content after scripts injection

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a website content but when I use ajax...

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type:'GET',
  async: false,
  success: (data) => websiteContent = data
});
```

I get only something like `<div class="root"></div>`. Is there a way to retreive a full webpage code after running all scripts?

Comment: `I get only something like <div class="root"></div>` - perhaps because that's what the request is retrieving? P.S. don't use `async:false`

Comment: Perhaps take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser though if any of the script run into CORS issues, you're not going to get the intended output

Comment: `async: true`, dosen't work, I'm using CORS chrome plugin

Comment: `async: true, dosen't work` it shouldn't make a difference to the result you're getting

Comment: So, its impossbile? :<